# Quoting issue with expect script

Tags: expect

I have a script to automatically connect to a VPN, because I often have to connect and disconnect several times a day.  (Certain things like ScreenHero and GoToMeeting fail on the VPN, and Mail servers and other things are blocked while on the VPN, *but* I can't connect to the Git server unless I'm on the VPN, and the app I'm working on can't reach certain back-end services unless I'm on the VPN, so development is limited when disconnected.)

The script lessens the hassle, but I have a `$` in my password (which is available in the environment through the environment variable `VPN_PASSWORD`<sup>1</sup>), and the password value gets interpolated before it is passed to the VPN program by expect.

```
#!/bin/bash

{
  /usr/bin/expect << END_OF_LOGIN_SESSION
  set timeout 30
  spawn /opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn -s connect blah.blahblah.com
  expect "Username:*"
  send "\r"
  expect "Password:*"
  send "$VPN_PASSWORD\r"
  expect "accept? \[y/n\]:*"
  send "y\r"
  expect eof
END_OF_LOGIN_SESSION
}
```

How do I pass a password literally, without letting it be subject to string interpolation?

Changing my password is a cop-out.  Saving it with a `\` is also a cop-out (and horrible UX, since I have to enter it every time I source my `.project` file for this project<sup>2</sup>).

It seems like expect must have a solution for this.

---

1. Yes I know someone who steals my laptop could try to log in, but (a) they'd have to get into my account first, and (b) they'd fail without my PIN, entered by phone, anyway.
2. No, the password is not saved to disk.  I enter it once per shell session related to this project.

Comment: Environmental variable name is `VPN_PASSWORD` ?

Comment: The `expect "*"` lines are useless and can be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the shell variable `$VPN_PASSWORD` in an unquoted heredoc, so the shell will substitute the value. Suppose `VPN_PASSWORD='foo$bar'` => Then expect will see: `send "foo$bar\r"` and you'll get `can't read "bar": no such variable`. The solution is to use `{braces}` instead of double quotes, so that expect will *not* attempt to expand the "inner" variable.

```
send {$VPN_PASSWORD}; send "\r"
```

You need a separate `send "\r"` because putting `\r` inside the braces will remove its special meaning, and Tcl won't let you do `send {$VPN_PASSWORD}"\r"`

Here's a demo:

```
$ VPN_PASSWORD='foo$bar'
$ expect <<END
send_user "$VPN_PASSWORD\n"
END
can't read "bar": no such variable
    while executing
"send_user "foo$bar\n""
$ expect <<END
send_user {$VPN_PASSWORD}; send_user "\n"
END
foo$bar
```

In Tcl, braces act like single quotes in the shell: everything inside them are literal characters.

---

It might be cleaner to use the environment to pass the values. Here it is implemented as a shell function

```
vpnconnect() {
    expect <<'END'
        set timeout 30
        spawn /opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn -s connect $env(VPN_HOST)
        expect "Username:*"
        send "\r"
        expect "Password:*"
        send "$env(VPN_PASSWORD)\r"
        expect {accept? [y/n]:*}
        send "y\r"
        expect eof
END
}
```

Comment: Thanks—that was an amazing answer.  I've never used Tcl before, so thanks for explaining the things that maybe should have been obvious, but weren't.

Comment: Tcl's syntax is amazingly simple. The whole language can be described on [one page](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm). Spending some time there will be a good investment.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that, mainly just to expand my knowledge of alternative languages, and alternative ways of doing things.

Answer (score 2):

You should have got the `can't read "VPN_PASSWORD": no such variable`  at the first place unless you have defined any variable with that name.

Environmental variables can be accessed via the Tcl's special array variable `env`.

You can straightaway use `env(VPN_PASSWORD)` to access the same.

```
send "$env(VPN_PASSWORD)\r"
```

**Reference :** [env](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/tclvars.htm#M4)